# Display a PDF inside a frame created within another PDF using JavaScript in Adobe Acrobat

Tags: javascript, pdf, acrobat

I want to display the selected pages of a PDF(existing in local machine) inside a window/frame of another PDF file(existing in local machine) in ADOBE Acrobat. How can i go about it . I searched online but i seem to not find any solution . If there is any other way to do this without using java script, is acceptable too.

Comment: PDFs don't contain windows or frames.

Comment: Possibly if you use flash and find a flash viewer that can show a pdf.

Answer (score 0):

You may have missed the keywords…

What is pretty common and easy to implement is importing the according page as an icon in a Button field.

The simplest approach would be using the `buttonImportIcon()` Acrobat JavaScript method (note the requirements for higher privileges). This method allows you to specify the file and the page to be imported.

Comment: is there any source where i can get to know more about it !?

Comment: You will need the Acrobat JavaScript documentation, which is part of the Acrobat SDK (documentation). You can download it from the Adobe website (http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat.html), then get the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only doing this when you're authoring the PDF and it doesn't need to be dynamically created, you can simply add a button field and then set the icon property to the PDF you want to show. If you need to do it programmatically, Max's answer will also work.

[image]

Comment: is there any way i can use multiple icons(like a PDF with 5 pages) within the same button where i can scroll them !?

Comment: Yes. In that case, you'd store each page of the embedded PDF as an icon at the document level and then set the buttonIcon to the appropriate "page" icon based on some sort of UI to scroll through the pages. In that case, you will need JavaScript. I've done something similar with animated GIFs in PDF. The process requires two stages, one to import the PDF as separate icons and then the script to navigate through them via the button icon. It's not complicated to code unless you're new to Acrobat JavaScript.

Comment: yes i started working on acrobat java script from a week. I am still trying to figure out whats happening. can u please help me out on this !?

Comment: Put your project down for a few days and get the basics first. Start here http://khkonsulting.com/2017/01/learning-to-program-javascript-for-adobe-acrobat/